# Liferay Webservice JSON response type

Tags: ios, web-services, liferay

I have a web service in liferay.. and the response would be

```
{"response":{"status":{"code":"200","message":"ok"},"userProfile":  {"screenName":"testUser","userName":"testUser"}}}
```

I'm getting following error when consuming it from an ios client:

```
Encountered unexpected response with status code: 200 (MIME Type: text/javascript)
The MIME type must be application/json for json resonse; please change
```

Where to configure in Liferay to make the MIME type to be "application:json"

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a servlet ..
- from the doGet method 
  set  response.setContentType("application/json");
- then add this servlet in the web.xml

response mime type would be "application/json"

Answer (score 0):

I think it needs to be configured in your **ios client** rather than in Liferay.

Since Liferay is sending the response as desired and the error you are getting is on the client side.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, actually there is a way to parse text/html type, but it would hve performance issue, its better if the response would be text/json